# How do you breed a Paper Dragon in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

Backflip studios has announced the one year anniversary of Dragonvale will include a limited dragon called the Paper Dragon. What is the best dragon combination to breed it and what is its breeding time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Paper Dragon** is bred by combining four elements:

- **Fire**
- **Earth**
- **Plant** and
- **Cold**

Source: [Dragonvale Wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Paper_Dragon)

Comment: For reference, I have gotten two now with Blue Fire and Moss, which supports your answer.

Comment: I got it with Lava and Lichen. I'm pretty sure any combination with these four elements will give it.

Answer (score 1):

- Poison and mountain
- Blue fire and tree
- Lava and lichen

Comment: Hi Issi, welcome to the site. How does this list relate to the previous answers?

Comment: While terribly short, this answer is accurate.  All of those breeding pairs fit the bill.